Extract file name hierarchy from .zip to .txt using cmd
I have a multi layer archive and I want to make a text file that shows it's hierarchy preferably through command prompt but if there are online tools or this requires some other tool like VS to be downloaded that's also fine.

Example of how output text file could look:


MAIN FOLDER
    FOLDER 1
        File.exe
        File2.txt
    FOLDER 2
        Archive1.zip
            FOLDER 1
                File.pdf
            FOLDER 2
                File.pdf
                File.txt



Need to somehow get file/folder names and their file extensions written down in a hierarchy in a .txt.
Tried looking on the web for an answer but can't seam to locate any guides, all results just talk about how to extract files via cmd.
